# Automate DBs restore through TSQL by given folders

Tags: restore

I searched in the internet but cannot find clear and direct way. I have a folder which include 100 databases as full backup, another folder contains all logs for these 100 DBs.

I need a script to do the automate restore for these DBs?

The names for backup files are different, for example

Adventure_Work_06162015_220000.bak
Adventure_Work_06012015_150000.bak

and so on, appreciate your help and cooperation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use <kbd>**[Restore Gene](https://paulbrewer.wordpress.com/2014/08/15/restore-gene-version-3-free-public-framework-technical-article/)**</kbd> written by Paul Brewer.

There is a T-SQL [`sp_RestoreGene`] and PowerShell version [`ps_RestoreGene`] of it and you can use it / customize it as per your needs.

SQLServerCentral.com has an excellent article by the author on how to configure and describes the working of it as well - [Restore Gene : Automating SQL Server Database Restores](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Restore/111917/).