# How to get an exclusive connection in AutoRestore job ( sp_RestoreGene)?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am using Paul Brewer's script for `AutoRestore sp_RestoreGene` on SQL Server 2008R2 box.

I created the stored procedure `dbo.sp_RestoreGene` on the Server 1 where the backup file is located.

I called the store procedure:

```
USE [DBA_]
DECLARE @RC int
EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[sp_RestoreGene]
@Database = 'Production'
,@TargetDatabase = 'Test'
,@WithRecovery = 1
,@WithCHECKDB = 1
,@WithReplace = 1
,@FromFileFullUNC = '\\Server1\Restore_backup\Backup\FullBackupForTest\'
,@Log_Reference = 'Incident xyz' 

GO
```

It generated the following Restore script.  I created a job which runs the script below in scheduled time on Server 2

```
;DECLARE @msg_Production VARCHAR(1000)
;RESTORE DATABASE [Test] FROM DISK = N'\\Server1\Restore_backup\Backup\FullBackupForTest\Production.bak'  WITH REPLACE, FILE = 2, NORECOVERY, STATS=10, MOVE N'Production' TO 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Test.mdf', MOVE N'Production_log' TO 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Test_log.ldf'
;SET @msg_Production = 'Incident xyz';  RAISERROR (@msg_Production,0,0) WITH LOG;RESTORE DATABASE [Test] WITH RECOVERY
;SET @msg_Production = 'Incident xyz';  RAISERROR (@msg_Production,0,0) WITH LOG;DBCC CHECKDB('Test') WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS
```

I got an error:

> Msg 3101, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Exclusive access could not be
>   obtained because the database is in use. Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 2  RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

To get the exclusive connection when I restore manually I use the script below . It works perfect.

```
use master
Go
ALTER DATABASE Test SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 
waitfor delay '00:00:05' -- 5 sec delay .. no other spid takes our space !
GO
```

Restore script

```
Go
ALTER DATABASE Test SET MULTI_USER 
go
```

Can I include in the restore script the `alter single user` and `alter set multi_user` script? Or is there a better way to get exclusive connection for autorestore?

How to get exclusive connection for Auto restore ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get exclusive database access (provided it is not used in replicaiton or logshipping or any other HA/DR), OFFLINE it.

```
ALTER DATABASE DB_name 
SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Make this as a first step and then run the restore script that you generated.

BTW, its  [Paul Brewer's restore gene script that you are using.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/104191/8783)

Comment: thank you I corrected paul full name. It is not used in replication or logshipping . It works perfect

Comment: @SQL_DBA_Bini Glad that it helped !